# Hide image and show text on hover Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following  code:

```js
$(".service-link").mouseover(function () {
      $(this).find('img:first').hide();
      var txt = $(this).attr("data-text");
      $(this).text(txt);
    }).mouseout(function () {
        $(this).text();
      $(this).find('img:first').show();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="servicesNav">
    <li class="servSep"><a class="service-link" data-text="Name A" href="#"><img id="serv-image-1" src="content/images/serv-1.png" /></a></li>
    <li class="servSep"><a class="service-link" data-text="Name A" href="#"><img id="serv-image-8" src="content/images/serv-8.png" /></a></li>
    <li class="servSep"><a class="service-link" data-text="Name C" href="#"><img id="serv-image-3" src="content/images/serv-3.png" /></a></li>
</ul>
```

Now what I'm trying to do it on hovering on each or the `li`, I am trying to hide the image and show a text instead of the image and on hover out it goes back to show the image without the text. This is where I get stuck. The image changes to the text but it stays on the text when I'm not hovering anymore, so the image doesn't come back.

Can anyone help on this?

Comment: you should have added a span will text and just toggle the image or span on hover

Comment: @guradio An example would greatly help :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(".service-link").mouseover(function() {
  $(this).find('img').toggle();
  $(this).find('span').toggle();
}).mouseout(function() {
  $(this).find('img').toggle();
  $(this).find('span').toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="servicesNav">
  <li class="servSep">
    <a class="service-link" data-text="Name A" href="#">
      <img id="serv-image-1" src="content/images/serv-1.png" />
      <span style="display:none">Name A</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="servSep">
    <a class="service-link" data-text="Name A" href="#">
      <img id="serv-image-8" src="content/images/serv-8.png" />
      <span style="display:none">Name B</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="servSep">
    <a class="service-link" data-text="Name C" href="#">
      <img id="serv-image-3" src="content/images/serv-3.png" />
      <span style="display:none">Name C</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

1. Create a span with the text.
2. Toggle both img and span accordingly

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use css to do that.
No need js.

```css
ul li a:hover img {
  display: none
}

ul li a:hover span {
  display: block
}

ul li a img {
  display: block
}

ul li a span {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<ul id="servicesNav">
    <li class="servSep"><a class="service-link" data-text="Name A" href="#"><span>Name A</span><img id="serv-image-1" src="content/images/serv-1.png" /></a></li>
    <li class="servSep"><a class="service-link" data-text="Name B" href="#"><span>Name B</span><img id="serv-image-8" src="content/images/serv-8.png" /></a></li>
    <li class="servSep"><a class="service-link" data-text="Name C" href="#"><span>Name C</span><img id="serv-image-3" src="content/images/serv-3.png" /></a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved by just using css. Toggle display property on hover of parent.

Example Snippet:

```css
#servicesNav .servSep span {
  display: none;
}
#servicesNav .servSep:hover span {
  display: inline;
}
#servicesNav .servSep:hover .image-tag {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul id="servicesNav">
  <li class="servSep">
    <a class="service-link" data-text="Name A" href="#">
      <img id="serv-image-1" class="image-tag" src="content/images/serv-1.png" />
      <span>SomeText</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="servSep">
    <a class="service-link" data-text="Name A" href="#">
      <img id="serv-image-8" class="image-tag" src="content/images/serv-8.png" />
      <span>SomeText</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="servSep">
    <a class="service-link" data-text="Name C" href="#">
      <img id="serv-image-3" class="image-tag" src="content/images/serv-3.png" />
      <span>SomeText</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Note: Use `jQuery` or `css` whichever you find more comfortable.