# Image shows text beside it when on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I'm trying to add some animation for my "Social Media" buttons where when hovering over one of the icon(s), there will be a little bit of animation showing what kind of Social network it is (e.g. Stackoverflow) or a little bit more details regarding that social network. But I can't get them to work, and the least option I can do is use the `Title`.

I already found some results, but it doesn't match to what I need and what I want for my HTML, here's the link: [Hide image and show text on hover Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41799056/hide-image-and-show-text-on-hover-jquery)

And I tried using this [Hide/show text on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51505497/hide-show-text-on-hover), but it doesn't match for what I have in mind since my icons are too small for them... Here's the "Social Network" part I'm working on and a screenshot of what they look like
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kom8I.png

```
        <p>I Have lots of Social Media Accounts too! You can check them if you like to!</p>

        <a href="https://codepen.io/Loremipsu/" target="_blank"><img src="files/images/Icons/codepen.png" alt="Codepen" title="Codepen"></a>
        <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/users/10825796/rodel" target="_blank"><img src="files/images/Icons/stackoverflow.png" alt="Stackoverflow" title="Stackoverflow"></a>
        <a href="https://github.com/Lolimipsu" target="_blank"><img src="files/images/Icons/github.png" alt="Github" title="Github"></a>
        <a href="https://www.reddit.com/user/MxLoli" target="_blank"><img src="files/images/Icons/reddit.png" alt="Reddit" title="Reddit"></a>
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com" target="_blank"><img src="files/images/Icons/youtube.png" alt="Youtube" title="Youtube"></a>
        <a href="https://disqus.com" target="_blank"><img src="files/images/Icons/disqus.png" alt="Disqus" title="Disqus"></a>


        <p>I also Play a lot of games, if you're interested here's a banner in one of my games ^w^</p>

        <a href="https://www.torn.com/1980558" target="_blank"><img src="https://www.torn.com/sigs/4_1980558.png" /></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

As I said before, the least thing I can do about it is using `title` tag
and what I have in my mind is this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOPpq.jpg

but doesn't cover other social icons, like this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/klTFR.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Checkout this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j4b59zo3/)

Try adding your sample text within a span in your anchor tag and then set the style as display none. Later on hover set the display as inline-block. See the above fiddle for reference. I hope this helps.

```
.sampleText {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: none;
  padding: 2px;
}


a:hover .sampleText {
  display: inline-block
}
```

Comment: Definitely what I'm looking for, thanks. But can you suggest a animation for it? Like from jquery? I kinda want it to have a little bit of animation, like when you hover on it, it will have a soft transition and a little delay on showing the text?